# multiple network interface ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu server, and the Apache web server is installed, along with two physical network cards, I want to connect to the web server from the outside with two fixed IPs, but in the default mode, the network card responds to one request from the outside He answers, this problem is solved in the routing table, but by turning off and on the server or the network card, the settings are cleared, thank you for your help.

```
route static ok
echo 700 adsl1 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
 echo 600 adsl2 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
 ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 src 192.168.1.130 table adsl1
 ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table adsl1
 ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.0.189 table adsl2
 ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 table adsl2
 ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 src 192.168.1.130
 ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.0.189
 ip rule add from 192.168.1.130 table adsl1
 ip rule add from 192.168.0.189 table adsl2
```

Comment: welcome, just for me before i can follow up - these commands are working? because if so, we can just put it into the network configuration file and then use if-up and down script to do automatically

Comment: Yes it works for me

Comment: Now, you'll have to check what is/are the tool(s) managing your network. There are sometimes more than one at the same time, and you have to pick what's best suited. Some of the tools can handle it themselves in their native configuration language (ie: the tool can handle policy-based routing), some others can't but can run arbitrary hooks for this, such as your commands. If you can't proceed on your own, you should figure out  what tool(s) are used to configure your system and provide information about it/them in the question.